# Music suddenly stops playing in C# Windows Form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, media

In my app there should normally be 2 sounds that overlap (a song and some short sounds). It works fine until from time to time the song suddenly stops playing. Do you know how I could solve this issue?
Here are the functions that I used for adding the songs and the sounds:

```cs
private void musical()
{
    var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    p1.Open(new System.Uri(@"J:\penalty\penalty\penalty\bin\Debug\Avicii - The Nights (Lyrics HD).wav"));
    p1.Play();     
}
private void happy()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"J:\penalty\penalty\penalty\bin\Debug\happy.wav"));
    p2.Play();
}
private void sad()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"J:\penalty\penalty\penalty\bin\Debug\sad.wav"));
    p2.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store a reference to the `MediaPlayer`s as field but only in local variables they are likely going to be gargabe collected. This might happen delayed as `MediaPlayer` uses unmanaged resources that would require a `Dispose` before being freed. To fix your problem consider storing a reference to the `MediaPlayer`s in a field.

```
private System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer _music;
private System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer _happy;
private System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer _sad;
```

and then adjust your methods to  use the field instead.

```
private void musical()
{
    _music = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    _music.Open(new System.Uri(@"J:\penalty\penalty\penalty\bin\Debug\Avicii - The Nights (Lyrics HD).wav"));
    _music.Play();     
}
```

If you would like to repeat the audio (which does not work very well) you can subscribe the `MediaEnded` event in order set the position back to the beginning and start playing again.